# Split Pot question?

Tags: texas-hold-em, reading-hands

The shared cards on the table are 7,9,10,J,Q of Random suits with no flush possibility. One player has 8,8 and the other has 8,9.  Is this a split pot since they both have a straight of 8-Q?  Or does it make a difference that one player has the 8,9 in the hole?

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a split pot. Only the **best** five card hand each player can make matters at showdown, at least in Texas Hold 'em. The other two cards are irrelevant, whether they make an additional pair or extend the length of a straight. When the board makes something better than what you're holding, it's called getting counterfeited.

Comment: On a side note and depending on the house rules, the only time when the hole cards makes a difference is when the pot is split and there are odd chips left. In this case, the odd chip goes to the one with the highest card, either by value or by suit.

Comment: @osmiumbin Really? That seems silly. Why not just award it to the first player to the left of the dealer as is usually done for odd chips?

Comment: Its not a standard poker rule. Each house has either one or the other rule. Tbh i would award it to the best hand and not according to position.

Comment: In B&M poker the odd chip always goes to the player left of the dealer.